# How do I send a unique row index every time the click event of a row data is fired in form IO data-grid?

Tags: datagrid, formio

I want to send the row index on a click event of every row in form IO Datagrid so that I can select a unique record and perform an operation on that.

I have a button and on click of that I am calling an event in my angular code from form IO. I want to pass the row index so I can identify each row uniquely.

Comment: Please include the code you have so far.

Comment: i have added an event in my code if ($event.type === Enums.CustomEvents.x) { //Do something}. I have called this event from form io and it triggers successfully.but how do i pass unique id from formio so it should accepted as unique key. i cannot paste whole code as it is configurable half in formio

Comment: @smsh  I have the same problem..could you pls provide me the solution